# When split strings, how to skip the field containing spaces?

Tags: python, string, split

I'm new to programming and I'm writing a code that deals with specific strings, it splits the input strings into two parameters.
The input string looks like this:

```
Foo 15
Bar 2
```

I use splitlines() in the code to split them line by line, and then use split() to further split into lists like this:

```
data = "Foo 15\nBar 2\n"
data_lines = data.splitlines()
for data in data_lines:
    print ("{} x {}".format(data.split()[0],data.split()[1])) #[0] is the name, [1] is the number
```

But in some cases, the input string will have names with space like this:

```
Foo - bar 15
Foo II 6
Foo S 100
```

In this case, data.split() will return wrong result and cause error like `ValueError: Field 'stock' expected a number but got '-'.`

So, my question is in the title, how to detect these fields with spaces and split them as one element? Any suggestions or guidance will do, thank you.

Comment: What does the data look like? Is there any pattern/format to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [rsplit](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rsplit.asp)

Specify one split starting from right end.

```
s = """Foo - bar 15
Foo II 6
Foo S 100"""

for data in s.splitlines():
  name, value = data.rsplit(' ', maxsplit = 1)
  print ("{} x {}".format(name, value))
```

**Output**

```
Foo - bar x 15
Foo II x 6
Foo S x 100
```